# Android sqlite from pc

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a pre-baked sqlite database that I want to use in my Android application.

I've followed this tutorial: 
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

However nothing is throwing an exception during the process of building and copying the db,
but when I access the db tables, they are not there, like they don't exist.

I made this sql query:

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master", null).getCount();
```

and I got the answer: 1. (I have 5 tables)

Any help?

Comment: try to copy the DB from android to PC and open in some database GUI explorer so you could see how it looks like exactly. you can copy it easily from eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial there is too old.  Try the following steps:

1) Create a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and overwrite the onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods

2) In some Activity instantiate your class, created in 1) and that's it - you will have your database created under data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/

3) If you want after that, you may obtain writable instance from the class created in 1) (`getWritableDatabase()`) and execute insert statements towards your database to populate it with data. Wrap your data in [ContentValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) and use `insertOrThrow(your_table_name, null, your_content_values)`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) in order to test your SQL .

I usually have the same problems like you , then what i'm used to do is extract de DB from the emulator data , and then use the program (in my case i use de [SQLite Database Browser Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqlite_database_browser_portable))

you can see data , make SQL Querys and a few more things .

P.D: What i'm not sure if it has the capability to use triggers , but anyway it's a enough nice program in order to use it.